# Correctly Call a Method From Newly Created Object Pointer

Tags: c++, oop, syntax

I am a Java programmer who is taking a C++ class. I can successfully create my object on the stack by not using the "new" keyword.

```
SeatSelection premium(1,5);
premium.toString();
```

That code runs my toString() method correctly.

I am also attempting to create a new C++ object using the "new" keyword and then attempting to run the toString() method.

```
SeatSelection *premium = new SeatSelection(1,5);
```

I don't know the proper syntax for calling my toString() method.

What I have tried

```
premium.toString();     //doesn't compile, premium is of non-class type "SeatSelection*"
```

What is the syntax for calling a method using a object pointer?

Comment: Please start by reading a C++ book.

Comment: `(*premium).toString();` is correct, as well as `premium->toString()`.

Comment: There is no code below that statement.

Comment: The code below that statement was only a puts("Print out"); That never got printed.

Comment: +1 Because @KerrekSB is having a bad day, this is a common question for those moving from Java to C++. Not to mention, there would be no need for stackoverflow.com if we all read books like we were supposed to...

Comment: But none of the answers explain why the puts following does not run. I can't either

Comment: @Zak: If it's a common question, that's even worse, since there's much more material already available than there is about uncommon questions... :-(

Comment: @TimBergel: Impossible to guess from fragmentary hearsay of what the code might look like... whatever happened to the "reproducible, representative example"?

Comment: Give me a minute to update my question.

Comment: It turns out my real problem was not with my syntax. I don't even know what is going on. My question was answered, I just have to figure out what is actually going on.

Comment: @MorganK: If this question has no value to future visitors, would you consider deleting it? Think about someone who would find it as a search result.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Do you think I should delete it? I didn't know what the syntax for calling methods from objects were. I looked around for a while and couldn't find an answer for that, which this question now answers it. My code just has other problems now.

Comment: @MorganK: Up to you. If you think it has value and can help others with the problem that is being clearly described in the question, then by all means leave it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47804/discussion-between-morgan-k-and-kerrek-sb)

Comment: Here is a great [C++ tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/). In fact, I used it myself in my transition from Java to C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use operator `->` Along with `.` (dot) it is so-called class member access operator.

For example

```
SeatSelection *premium = new SeatSelection(1,5);
premium->toString();
```

Or you can write

```
SeatSelection *premium = new SeatSelection(1,5);
( *premium ).toString();
```

According to the C++ Standard

> expression E1->E2 is converted to the equivalent form (*(E1)).E2;

Answer (score 1):

In C++ anytime you use `new` you are creating an object on the heap and getting a pointer to that object in return.

In C++ there are two ways to deference a pointer.

1) Use an asterisk as in `(*premium)`, then use a dot operator to call a function on that class (i.e. `(*premium).toString();`).

2) Use the arrow `->` operator as suggested in other examples, which merges the functionality of the asterisk and dot in one fell swoop and "looks prettier" (i.e. `premium->toString();`).

**DON'T FORGET**
`C++` is *NOT* garbage collected like `Java`, so when you `new` up a class, you must have a matching `delete`, or you will be hemorrhaging memory.